# React update state with button only updates state once

Tags: reactjs, state, increment

I added a like button to my Blog component and the state updates on the backend, but it only happens once. Once I press the 'like' button, the state of the 'likes' count increases by one, but each proceeding call using the like button makes a PUT request but it doesn't increase the count.

App.js

```
import blogService from './services/blogs';
...

const App = () => {
  // All blogs display
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);
  ....

  const updateBlog = async blogObject => {
    const updatedBlog = await blogService.update(blogObject.id, blogObject);
    setBlogs(
      blogs.map(blog => (blog.id !== updatedBlog.id ? blog : updatedBlog)),
    );
    console.log(updatedBlog);
    setMessage(`Liked "${updatedBlog.title}"`);
    setMessageClass('success');
    setTimeout(() => {
      setMessage(null);
      setMessageClass('none');
    }, 3000);
  };

...

return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <p className={messageClass}>{message}</p>

        <p>{user.name} is logged in </p>
        {logOutForm()}
        <hr />
        <br />
        {blogForm()}
        <hr />
        <ul>
          {blogs.map(blog => (
            <Blog key={blog.id} blog={blog} updateBlog={updateBlog} />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
```

blogs.js (blogService)

```
import axios from 'axios';
const baseUrl = '/api/blogs';

....

const update = (id, newObject) => {
  const request = axios.put(`${baseUrl}/${id}`, newObject);
  return request.then(response => response.data);
};
```

Blog.js component

```
const Blog = ({ blog, updateBlog }) => {
  ...

  const [blogObject, setBlogObject] = useState(blog);

  const likeBlog = () => {
    let likes = blog.likes + 1;
    // Make a copy of the blog object and pass new likes count
    const editedBlog = { ...blog, likes };
    updateBlog(editedBlog);
    setBlogObject(editedBlog);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ListGroup variant className='m-3'>
        <div style={hideWhenVisible}>
          <ListGroup.Item>{blog.title} </ListGroup.Item>
          <Button
            onClick={toggleVisibility}
            style={buttonStyle}
            variant='primary'
          >
            View
          </Button>
        </div>
        <div style={showWhenVisible}>
          <ListGroup.Item>{blog.title} </ListGroup.Item>
          <ListGroup.Item>{blog.url}</ListGroup.Item>
          <ListGroup.Item>{blog.author}</ListGroup.Item>
          <ListGroup.Item>
            <Button
              variant='success'
              type='submit'
              style={{ marginLeft: '8px' }}
              onClick={likeBlog}
            >
              {blogObject.likes} likes
            </Button>
          </ListGroup.Item>
          <Button
            onClick={toggleVisibility}
            style={buttonStyle}
            variant='secondary'
          >
            Hide
          </Button>
        </div>
        <hr style={hrStyle} />
      </ListGroup>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Blogs.js (controllers folder in backend)

```
blogsRouter.put('/:id', async (request, response, next) => {
  const body = request.body;

  const blog = {
    author: body.author,
    title: body.title,
    url: body.url,
    likes: body.likes,
  };

  try {
    // Update command
    const editedBlog = await Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(request.params.id, blog, {
      new: true,
    });
    editedBlog.toJSON();
  } catch (exception) {
    next(exception);
  }
});
```

console each time the 'Like' button is pressed

```
---
Method: PUT
Path:   /api/blogs/61106affab47f571ae71e6c1
Body:   {
  likes: 9,
  title: 'My first blog',
  author: 'Mickey Daniels',
  url: 'http://localhost3003/api/blogs',
  id: '61106affab47f571ae71e6c1'
}
---
Method: PUT
Path:   /api/blogs/61106affab47f571ae71e6c1
Body:   {
  likes: 9,
  title: 'My first blog',
  author: 'Mickey Daniels',
  url: 'http://localhost3003/api/blogs',
  id: '61106affab47f571ae71e6c1'
}
---
Method: PUT
Path:   /api/blogs/61106affab47f571ae71e6c1
Body:   {
  likes: 9,
  title: 'My first blog',
  author: 'Mickey Daniels',
  url: 'http://localhost3003/api/blogs',
  id: '61106affab47f571ae71e6c1'
}
---
```

You see above in the console that a PUT request is made each time, but 'Likes' is not incremented.

Comment: Great analysis of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, you need to add a `useEffect` hook in your `Blog` component to read the `blog` again once changed, such like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setBlogObject(blog)
}, [blog]);
```

this will update the `likes` count as it comes from your API response to the update call, but, from my own point of view, you can directly rely on `blog` property on `Blog` component, and just compute any other values on the run without the need of stalling with a state hook.

===========

## Update #1

Another way to do that is by updating the `blog` reference to the most recent one (which you store in Blog's component state).

```
  const likeBlog = () => {
    let likes = blogObject.likes + 1;
    // Make a copy of the blog object and pass new likes count
    const editedBlog = { ...blogObject, likes };
    updateBlog(editedBlog);
    setBlogObject(editedBlog);
  };
```

Comment: Sultan, I did try both methods you mentioned and it does visually update the count, but it's not actually making the change on the backend and updating the database count, unless I manually refresh the page.

Comment: @JackJack I updated my answer, please let me know if the second part works.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Accepted this answer as the solution.